# Missing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell' ; please help me

Tags: swift

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "tasks") as! TaskViewController
    vc.title = "New Tasks"
    vc.task = tasks[indexPath.row]
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    //error:Missing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell'
}
    
  }
```

I try diffrence of return type but none of them are correct

Comment: Instantiating a view controller inside `cellForRow` is pointless. You have to dequeue and **return** a table view cell.

Comment: if you are trying to open tasks "view controller" when clicked on cell then use didSelectRow delegate method instead

Answer (score 1):

The process is wrong in this function you are supposed to create a cell instance and work with it to be able to return it

Code modified:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        /// Create a file for the cell let's say call it `myCell` with a label for task "let's suppose called `lblTaskOutlet`
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! myCell
        myCell.lblTaskOutlet = tasks[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
        
    }
}
```

You can add this `vc.title = "New Tasks"` in your `viewDidLoad()` :

```
self.title = "New Tasks"
```

The below line is another function called alone with its own body:

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```

Comment: can you please tell more specific please??:(((

Comment: Okay I will modify the answer

Comment: Answer already edited, check it @lekhoile

Answer (score 0):

tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell method is a tableview delegate method which populates the cells for each row. It is expecting a return type of UITableViewCell.
You can create UITableViewCell subclass `TaskCell`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    /// Create a file for the cell let's say call it `TaskCell` with a object for task "let's suppose called `taskObj`
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell
    cell.taskObj = tasks[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

For the click action on cell you have to override another `UITableViewDataSource` method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "tasks") as! TaskViewController
    vc.title = "New Tasks"
    vc.task = tasks[indexPath.row]
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

And please make sure that you have set tableview delegate and datasource in view did load of your view controller.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
}
```